# How to identify current_user to send data (ActiveCable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I would like to know if it's possible to use the method current_user into the coffee files where we send data ?

In my case, I'm creating some groups. And I made two container to differentiate yours and others. So I'm trying to make a condition in the received function. But I don't know how to do it (you can see one of the try in my code below).

So if you have a solution for that, it would be great !

My code :

Views(index) : with the two containers

```
<div class="col-sm-12"> 
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">Your groups</h1>
    <div id="groups_area">  
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">Other groups </h1>
    <div id="groups_out_area">     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The coffee file :

```
 received: (data) ->
    if data.group.admin_id == current_user.id
      $('#groups_area').append(data.group)
    else 
      $('#groups_out_area').append(data.group)
```

Should I have to catch it in the ActionCable file ? As you can see here, i've try to catch it in the speak method, but is not really logic

```
class GroupsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "groups"
  end

  def speak(data)
    group = Group.create(name: data['group'], company_id: current_user.company_id, admin_id: current_user.id)
    user_group = GroupsUser.create(user_id: current_user.id, group_id: group.id)
    html = ApplicationController.render(partial: 'groups/group', locals: {
      group: group
    })

    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'groups', group: html
  end 

end
```

Comment: You could pass `current_user.id` to a view and then get it in coffee file.

Comment: Thank for your help @yzalavin, but you don't know a way to call current_user directly into the coffee script ?

Comment: @yzalavin is suggesting loading the variable through `coffee.erb` or something, like `current_user_id = <%= current_user.id %>`. Keep in mind though that you can't rely on client-side logic to securely prevent users from seeing certain content; you need to make sure that the server publishes to only those users as well.